# To change the color of a text box using addAttributes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using `addAttributes` to change the color of all the textboxes present on the form and I am writing:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   For Each CTL In Page.Controls
      if TypeOf CTL Is TextBox Then
         Dim Txt = New TextBox

         Txt.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "javascript:this.style.background='yellow';")
         Txt.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "javascript:this.style.background='white';")
      End If
   Next
End If
```

There is no error on the page, but it does not work. Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 problems here.

First, you're creating a new TextBox each time you `New TextBox`. After creating the TextBox and setting the attributes, you seem to just discard it without actually using it. You should actually be using `CTL` directly instead of attempting to create a new instance `Txt`.

The second problem is that, you are only attempting to set the attributes for the direct child controls of the page. Let's say if your page have some tables or panels, and you TextBox is in those. You wouldn't be able to access them. You will need to recursively go through the control tree and set the attributes as necessary.

The code should look something like this:

```
Protected Sub SetTextBoxColor(ByVal parentCtl As Control)
    For Each ctl In parentCtl.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
            ctl.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "javascript:this.style.background='yellow';")
            ctl.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "javascript:this.style.background='white';")
        End If
        SetTextBoxColor(ctl)
    Next
End Sub
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        SetTextBoxColor(Page)
    End If
End Sub
```